# How to enforce the order of with_dict in Ansible?

Tags: loops, ansible

I have dictionary-type of data that I want to iterate through and keeping the order is important:

```
with_dict_test:
  one:   1
  two:   2
  three: 3
  four:  4
  five:  5
  six:   6
```

Now when I write a task to print the keys and values, they are printed in seemingly random order (6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2).

```
---
- name: with_dict test
  debug: msg="{{item.key}} --> {{item.value}}"
  with_dict: with_dict_test
```

How can I enforce Ansible to iterate in the given order? Or is there anything better suited than `with_dict`? I really need both the key and the value during task execution...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to use dicts as they determine there order from the order of its hashed keys.
You can do the following:

```
with_dict_test:
  - { key: 'one', value: 1 }
  - { key: 'two', value: 2 }
  - { key: 'three', value: 3 }
  - { key: 'four', value: 4 }
  - { key: 'five', value: 5 }
  - { key: 'six', value: 6 }
```

and in the playbook just replace `with_dict` with `with_items`:

```
---
- name: with_dict test
  debug: msg="{{item.key}} --> {{item.value}}"
  with_items: with_dict_test
```

If you find this solution (the declaration of the variable) to ugly, you can do this:

```
key: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and in the playbook

```
---
- name: with_dict test
  debug: msg="{{item.0}} --> {{item.1}}"
  with_together:
    - key
    - value
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did not know that the order is given by the hashed keys. Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: The whole playbook is a yaml document. Just have a look at http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation to see how it is parsed into python objects.

Comment: @SebastianStigler It helped me a lot. It's simply brilliant solution

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure, but maybe this will help you along the way:

```
  - hosts: localhost
    vars:
      dict:
        one: 1
        two: 2
        three: 3
      sorted: "{{ dict|dictsort(false,'value') }}"

    tasks:
      - debug:
          var: sorted
      - debug:
          msg: "good {{item.1}}"
        with_items: sorted
```

I'm assuming you can use the Jinja filter to somehow sort on complex values. Another thing you might check out is combining `dict.values()|list` and `with_sequence`, but anything you milk out of that stone won't exactly scream "maintainable."

Comment: Interesting approach. However, my example `with_dict_test` is just for illustration. In reality, I want the entries to be sorted by the given order in the file, neither sorted by the keys nor by the values...

Comment: @dokaspar Sorry about that -- for some reason I assumed you _had_ to deal with a dict (e.g. registered variable from another task)